# Shelf Life of Warm Beer

Tags: storage

I put my beer on a warm floor for a week (I live in Korea and during winter we keep our floor warm). Does this make my beer go bad enough that it's unhealthy to drink it?

The beer is Schneider Weisse Tap 5, and the shelf life written on the bottle says July 2018. I'm just concerned if the warm floor may have made the beer go bad real fast or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think any beer that has already been shipped around the world can probably take a week at slightly elevated temperatures. I don't think a week is going to hurt it, but a couple of months might. Relax and enjoy it!